# Bluetooth settings shows the error "No bluetooth adaptor found"

Tags: bluetooth, adapter

I'm gettng a "No bluetooth adaptor" found message under blutooth settings when i have an adaptor and it's on.

Why?

I have a sony vaio cr343nb.

Answer (score 1):

I found  the answer, well not exactly but it worked.I had to enable the bluetooth that i had disabled on my windows partition and then boot from my Ubuntu pen drive and it recognized the bluetooth device and worked perfectly. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Linux kernel was not made to work with proprietary drivers, so it's possible that if you're computer was manufactured with windows/mac in mind, there will be components that don't work. For instance, my dvd drive won't eject unless I push the button.Ubuntu has a compatibility site here:     http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/
Check to see if you're computer is "Ubuntu certified", otherwise there's no gurantees. And even then...